# How do I get the updated HTML from Symfony's DomCrawler component?

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony's DomCrawler component. I have it successfully retrieving nodes, adding and amending HTML.

However, I'm not sure how to actually get the HTML out at the end. I'm trying to get the HTML string after it has been changed by DomCrawler, but I can't find out how to do it.

There's no magic `__toString()` method (and it returns an error when I do `print $crawler`). There are no `get*()` methods, no properties with html as a value. I've tried a `vardump($crawler)` but that doesn't help.

---

UPDATE

If I use

```
$crawler->first()->ownerDocument->saveHtml()
```

it throws an exception about "calling the saveHtml() on a non-object", plus a PHP error of:

> Undefined property: Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler::$ownerDocument

I tried using eq(0) instead of first() but get the same error.

However, if I change to using

```
each( function($node, $i) { 
  print $i . " - " . $node; }
)
```

then it returns

```
0 - <html>...</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As this turns up pretty early when searching, i just wanted to point out that a method `html()` was added to the crawler in Symfony 2.3

See "[Manipulating and Dumping a Crawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#adding-the-content)" in the Symfony documentation.

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: As @dbu pointed out, since Symfony 2.3 it is possible to use the [`Crawler::html()`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#adding-the-content) method.

Crawler is a set (SplObjectStorage) of [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) objects. Knowing that you can use any method and property available in [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php), [DOMNode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) and also [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$html = '';

foreach ($crawler as $domElement) {
    $html.= $domElement->ownerDocument->saveHTML();
}

echo $html;
```

Useful links:

- [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php)
- [DOMNode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php)
- [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- [DomCrawler documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/dom_crawler.html).
- [DomCrawler API documentation](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html)

Comment: OK, I did this and it throws an exception about "calling the saveHtml() on a non-object". I tried using `eq(0)` instead of `first()` but get the same error. I changed to using `each( function($node, $i) { print $i . " - " . $node; } )` and that returns "0 - [the html]". It looks like my problem is a lack of understanding with SplObjectStorage - any pointers would be very welcome!

Comment: I was writing from memory and made a mistake. Every traversal Crawler method returns a Crawler instance. However, you can use a Crawler instance in a foreach loop and iterate through list of its DOMElement objects. I updated my answer.

Comment: Link to SplObjectStorage documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php

Comment: `->html()` gets you the `innerHTML`, not `outerHTML`

Comment: Symfony Crawler has an outerHtml method, too - but the problem with it is, that it does not return the doctype. @JakubZalas solution with the foreach loop seems indeed to be the only possibility to get the valid html including doctype.